# Redlaser SDK and nil modal view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Since upgrading to XCode 5/iOS 7, I'm getting the following error when calling a function which is supposed to present the Redlaser SDK barcodepickercontroller:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target .'
*** First throw call stack:

(

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02ef25e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180

1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028dd8b6 objc_exception_throw + 44

2   UIKit                               0x006e817a -[UIViewControllerpresentViewController:withTransition:completion:] + 4879

3   UIKit                               0x006e8caf -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 130
4   UIKit                               0x006e8cef -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:] + 56
5   Extinguishers                       0x0000b703 -[LoginViewController scanPressed] + 1299
```

And here's my method which causes it:

```
-(IBAction) scanPressed
{   
if (overlayController.parentPicker == nil)
{
    BarcodePickerController * picker = [[BarcodePickerController alloc] init];

    [picker setOverlay:overlayController]; 
    [picker setDelegate:self];

    // Initialize with portrait mode as default
    picker.orientation = UIImageOrientationUp;

    // The active scanning region size is set in OverlayController.m
}

// Update barcode on/off settings
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanUPCE:YES];
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanEAN8:YES];
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanEAN13:YES];
//[overlayController.parentPicker setScanSTICKY:YES];
//[overlayController.parentPicker setScanQRCODE:YES];
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanCODE128:YES];
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanCODE39:YES];
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanITF:YES];

// Data matrix decoding does not work very well so it is disabled for now
[overlayController.parentPicker setScanDATAMATRIX:NO];

// hide the status bar
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

// Show the scanner overlay - THIS LINE CAUSES THE CRASH
    [self presentModalViewController:overlayController.parentPicker animated:TRUE];
```

}

I've also tried upgrading to the latest version of the Redlaser SDK, and the error is still the same. I did not have this problem before switching to iOS 7 as the base SDK.

Comment: First of all, `presentModalViewController:animated:` was deprecated in iOS 6. Try using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Comment: Changed to that, but same error.

Comment: Try adding your picker as subview into current view and do a bringviewfront instead of presenting as model. just a work around

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that `picker`(the parent) might be going out of scope and getting deallocated. Put a test right before the buggy line to check if the parent still exists: `if(overlayController.parentPicker == nil) NSLog(@"Parent is nil");`

If it really is `nil` (like your original error is saying), try declaring `picker` **before** that first `if` statement.

```
BarcodePickerController *picker;
if(overlayController.parentPicker == nil)
{
    picker = [[BarcodePickerController alloc] init];
//...
```

The child might only have a `weak` pointer to the parent, so you may need to declare the parent as a `@property` or somewhere where it won't be deallocated before your `viewController` is popped off the stack.